# Ardupilot + ROS

Tags: ros, drone, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !
I have made a hexacopter with APM 2.8 and would love to deploy ROS on it using a Raspi. I aim to use opencv with ros to detect landing marker and make it land autonomously. But I don't know what camera to use! Any suggestions on this would be great.

Have looked into mavros_pkg

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319804/ardupilot-+-ros/) by [Yug Ajmera](https://answers.ros.org/users/39769/yug-ajmera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2019-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
i use [ps3 camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlayStation_Eye) for landing and take off with marker but if you want spent money i suggest you to buy [mvbluefox ~200](https://www.matrix-vision.com/USB2.0-industrial-camera-mvbluefox.html) this camera is global shutter but ps3 suffer from blur noise but ps3 camera is cheaper

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2019-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yug Ajmera](https://answers.ros.org/users/39769/yug-ajmera/) on 2019-03-28**:
Thanks ! What flight controller do you use ?

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2019-03-28**:
Px4 in lpe verstion